# How many devices can you test your iOS app on?

Tags: ios, testing, testflight

I have quite a lot of people who want to test out my app and I was wondering how many people Apple allows to download it before it's on the AppStore. Does this change if you use TestFlight?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 4):

[You're allowed up to 1000 "external testers"](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) for Apple's TestFlight service, as is described in the very top paragraph of Apple's TestFlight web page.

Comment: Just for completeness : if you don't use Apple's TestFlight service you can register 100 test devices or use an Enterprise profile which can be used on unlimited devices (but requires a separate, Enterprise Apple dev subscription).

Comment: Now increased to 500 test devices... http://techcrunch.com/2015/06/10/apple-increases-test-device-limits-for-developers-hinting-at-plans-for-apple-tv-apps/